# Kubernetes manifest service for deployment

Tags: kubernetes, manifest

So final manifest will be next :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apiserver-service
  labels:
    app: apiserver
spec:
  selector:
    app: apiserver
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30005
  type: NodePort
```

It will work for defining specific targetport

Comment: I tried to search for examples but didnt find anything similar. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service is an abstract way to expose your application running on a set of Pods. This one is a manifest for creating a `service`, here `targetPort: 8080` is the pod port. In this manifest there are basically two parts, one is `metadata` which gives the service name and also give it a label. Then the `spec` part, which is short form of specification, it basically the specification of the service, here the `selector` is given, and also the ports are specified here, `port` represents the service port, `targetPort` represents the port on which the service will send requests. By `nodePort` the outside world (from outside the cluster) can communicate to the service, and finally `type` represents the type of the service. If the `type = NodePort` then it is basically means from outside the cluster the service will expose a port (`nodePort`).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apiserver-service
  labels:
    app: apiserver
spec:
  selector:
    app: apiserver
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30005
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: thank you so much you saved me plenty of time.

Answer (score 1):

The first example in Kubernetes Service documentation [Defining a Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) contains what you ask, a Service where `port:` and `targetPort:` is different.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```

Comment: thank you as well! i appreciate your help